# Keras fit_generator doesn't predict the same as fit

Tags: python, image, keras

I'm trying to train a model in Keras for image segmentation (U-Net) and started off by generating two lists containing my train (and validation) images and masks. I then trained the model as is shown below.

```py
x_train_val = # list of images (nr_images, 256, 256, 3)
y_train_val = # list of masks (nr_images, 256, 256, 1)

# Define model
def standard_unet():
    inputs = Input((img_size, img_size, 3))

    s = Lambda(lambda x: x / 255) (inputs)

    c1 = Conv2D(8, (3, 3), activation='relu', padding='same') (inputs)
    c1 = Conv2D(8, (3, 3), activation='relu', padding='same') (c1)
    p1 = MaxPooling2D((2, 2)) (c1)

    c2 = Conv2D(16, (3, 3), activation='relu', padding='same') (p1)
    c2 = Conv2D(16, (3, 3), activation='relu', padding='same') (c2)
    p2 = MaxPooling2D((2, 2)) (c2)

    c3 = Conv2D(32, (3, 3), activation='relu', padding='same') (p2)
    c3 = Conv2D(32, (3, 3), activation='relu', padding='same') (c3)
    p3 = MaxPooling2D((2, 2)) (c3)

    c4 = Conv2D(64, (3, 3), activation='relu', padding='same') (p3)
    c4 = Conv2D(64, (3, 3), activation='relu', padding='same') (c4)
    p4 = MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2, 2)) (c4)

    c5 = Conv2D(128, (3, 3), activation='relu', padding='same') (p4)
    c5 = Conv2D(128, (3, 3), activation='relu', padding='same') (c5)

    u6 = Conv2DTranspose(64, (2, 2), strides=(2, 2), padding='same') (c5)
    u6 = concatenate([u6, c4])
    c6 = Conv2D(64, (3, 3), activation='relu', padding='same') (u6)
    c6 = Conv2D(64, (3, 3), activation='relu', padding='same') (c6)

    u7 = Conv2DTranspose(32, (2, 2), strides=(2, 2), padding='same') (c6)
    u7 = concatenate([u7, c3])
    c7 = Conv2D(32, (3, 3), activation='relu', padding='same') (u7)
    c7 = Conv2D(32, (3, 3), activation='relu', padding='same') (c7)

    u8 = Conv2DTranspose(16, (2, 2), strides=(2, 2), padding='same') (c7)
    u8 = concatenate([u8, c2])
    c8 = Conv2D(16, (3, 3), activation='relu', padding='same') (u8)
    c8 = Conv2D(16, (3, 3), activation='relu', padding='same') (c8)

    u9 = Conv2DTranspose(8, (2, 2), strides=(2, 2), padding='same') (c8)
    u9 = concatenate([u9, c1], axis=3)
    c9 = Conv2D(8, (3, 3), activation='relu', padding='same') (u9)
    c9 = Conv2D(8, (3, 3), activation='relu', padding='same') (c9)

    outputs = Conv2D(1, (1, 1), activation='sigmoid') (c9)

    model = Model(inputs=[inputs], outputs=[outputs])

    return model

# IoU metric
def mean_iou(y_true, y_pred):
    prec = []
    for t in np.arange(0.5, 1.0, 0.05):
        y_pred_ = tf.to_int32(y_pred > t)
        score, up_opt = tf.metrics.mean_iou(y_true, y_pred_, 2)
        K.get_session().run(tf.local_variables_initializer())
        with tf.control_dependencies([up_opt]):
            score = tf.identity(score)
        prec.append(score)
    return K.mean(K.stack(prec), axis=0)

# Dice coef loss
def dice_coef(y_true, y_pred):
    smooth = 1.
    y_true_f = K.flatten(y_true)
    y_pred_f = K.flatten(y_pred)
    intersection = K.sum(y_true_f * y_pred_f)
    return (2. * intersection + smooth) / (K.sum(y_true_f) + K.sum(y_pred_f) + smooth)

def bce_dice_loss(y_true, y_pred):
    return 0.5 * binary_crossentropy(y_true, y_pred) - dice_coef(y_true, y_pred)

# Model compiling
K.clear_session()
model = standard_unet()
model.compile(optimizer='adam', loss=bce_dice_loss, metrics=[mean_iou])

# Fitting
model.fit(x_train_val, y_train_val, validation_split=0.1, epochs=20)
```

This works exactly as intended and I get decent results when I try to predict on test images. As I want to increase the number of training images, I tried using `ImageDataGenerator` and `train_generator` using the following function.

```py
# Runtime data augmentation
def get_train_test_augmented(x_data=x_train_val, y_data=y_train_val, validation_split=0.1, batch_size=32):
    x_train, x_valid, y_train, y_valid = train_test_split(x_data, y_data,
                                                          train_size=1-validation_split,
                                                          test_size=validation_split)

    data_gen_args = dict(rotation_range=45.,
                         width_shift_range=0.1,
                         height_shift_range=0.1,
                         horizontal_flip=True,
                         vertical_flip=True,
                         fill_mode='reflect')  #use 'constant'??

    x_datagen = ImageDataGenerator(**data_gen_args)
    y_datagen = ImageDataGenerator(**data_gen_args)
    x_datagen.fit(x_train, augment=True)
    y_datagen.fit(y_train, augment=True)
    x_train_augmented = x_datagen.flow(x_train, batch_size=batch_size, shuffle=True)
    y_train_augmented = y_datagen.flow(y_train, batch_size=batch_size, shuffle=True)

    # combine generators into one which yields image and masks
    train_generator = zip(x_train_augmented, y_train_augmented)

    return train_generator
```

Visual inspection of these images shows, that they contain what I expect (augmented images and masks). However, when I now fit my model, my predictions are always blank.

```py
train_generator = get_train_test_augmented()
model.fit_generator(train_generator, epochs=20)
```

Has anyone experienced the same issue with blank image prediction or know how to solve it?
Thanks, BBQuercus.

Comment: Can you show us the model you are using?
Also have you tried first using an `ImageDataGenerator` that only flows through the arrays, that is without any data augmentation or normalisation to see if you are having the same results? Then you can progressively add data aug. and norm. (and other stuff like interpolation) to see where the error comes from.

Comment: no no add it to the question since it's not an answer (you can edit your question)

Comment: Ah I think I also spotted it, you are doing the image generation separately with the generators, what will happen is that the random transform will not be the same for the input image and the label (mask). Try seeding both generators with the same seed and see if it changes anything.

Comment: Actually even more than that, you are shuffling both, so they do not even correspond to one another. I would advise seeding both with the same seed again or creating a custom Sequence.

Comment: See here for instance : https://github.com/keras-team/keras/issues/3059#issuecomment-364787723

Comment: So you mean I should combine image and mask into one datagen? I'm just training with empty `ImageDataGenerators`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/200116/discussion-between-bbquercus-and-zaccharie-ramzi).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are doing the image generation separately with the image and mask generators, what will happen is that the random transform will not be the same for the input image and the label (mask). 
Even more than that, you are shuffling both generators, so they do not even correspond to one another (the image and the mask in fit generator).

[This github issue comment](https://github.com/keras-team/keras/issues/3059#issuecomment-364787723) also talks about that, and suggest creating an extra generator to merge both.

Try seeding both generators with the same seed and see if it changes anything.

---

EDIT

As I was working with image denoising, I noticed that the solution using `zip` is suboptimal because you can't make use of `use_multiprocessing=True` when fitting. A solution is to implement a custom generator merger:

```py
class MergedGenerators(Sequence):
    def __init__(self, *generators):
        self.generators = generators
        # TODO add a check to verify that all generators have the same length

    def __len__(self):
        return len(self.generators[0])

    def __getitem__(self, index):
        return [generator[index] for generator in self.generators]

train_generator = MergedGenerators(image_generator, mask_generator)
```

Comment: The loss and metrics are now also performing properly. Just followed the merging performed on from the link.

Comment: @BBQuercus make sure you check my edit to be able to work with multiprocessing in a thread safe way.